# Cron job still running when deleted

Tags: cron, notifications

On a server I inherited, there is a `cron` job running hourly on one of the Debian servers. It sends an email out to a non-existent email, but bounces back to my account since I listed myself as the `root` email in `/etc/aliases`. The cron job has been deleted from `/etc/cron.hourly` (it was `ntupdate`), as it's listed in the email. I reloaded the `crontab` daemon, but I am still getting hourly reports that the file failed to launch, and the email address does not exist!

The output that is getting emailed:

```
/etc/cron.hourly/ntpdate:
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/cron.hourly/ntpdate: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/cron.hourly/ntpdate exited with return code 1
```

Currently, there is just the `.placeholder` hidden file in `/etc/cron.hourly`. I also ran `crontab -l`, and the only 3 jobs listed are expected to be listed, and are running about 10 minutes after this email keep arriving; so I know it is not one of those. **Where can I look next to stop getting these emails?**

**EDIT #1**

```
# ls -l /var/spool/cron
total 4
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab 4096 Jan 25  2012 crontabs
```

**EDIT #2**

```
# ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
total 4
-rw------- 1 root crontab 311 Jan 25  2012 root
# more /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.4nUf85/crontab installed on Wed Jan 25 10:11:10 2012)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
2 1 * * * /etc/webmin/cron/tempdelete.pl
0 22 * * * /etc/init.d/gnugk stop
0 23 * * * /etc/init.d/gnugk start
```

This is on Debian Squeeze, using just `cron`, as far as I can tell

Comment: What distribution is this (I assume you are on Linux)? Which cron? There are differences between the implementations on different distros. How did you reload the `cron` daemon? Is rebooting the server an option?

Comment: Are these emails really coming from that server?   Are they recent?

Comment: @terdon Updated. Can reboot, but would prefer not to

Comment: @sendmoreinfo Yes, they are coming from the root@*servername* account. They are happening at 29 minutes past the hour, every hour

Comment: And I imagine you have run `service cron restart`?

Comment: @terdon Yes. Just did it again, even though there weren't any changes

Comment: Still got it, 12:29pm

Comment: Maybe you have multiple crons running? `killall -TERM cron && service cron restart`. Then my next port of call would be a more brute force search `grep -r ntpdate /etc/cron*`.

Comment: Is that time for e-mail reception or sending? Just wondering if the cron has already stopped but you are still receiving a backlog of failure e-mails.

Comment: Cannot find ntupdate anywhere in /etc/cron*. Restarted after killing, waiting

Comment: @PauloAlmeida You may be on to something... Email is sent at xx:17... So it's taking 12 minutes to fail

Comment: You said you couldn't find `ntupdate`, but the error message is about `ntpdate`. Was that a typo?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida I deleted it yesterday, and I'm still gettign emails today

Comment: Cron logs what it does in `/var/log/syslog`. What recent log entries do you see there (search for `CRON`)?

Comment: Any virtual machines on the box?

Comment: @sendmoreinfo No, there isn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### system crons

Did you look through these files & directories to make sure there isn't a duplicate cronjob present?

- /etc/crontab
- /etc/cron.hourly/
- /etc/cron.d/
- /etc/cron.daily/
- /etc/cron.hourly/
- /etc/cron.monthly/
- /etc/cron.weekly/

Also any files present in these directories that's executable will be run. Doesn't matter if it's a .placeholder name or whatever. You can use `chmod 644 ...` to disable any script that is executable.

#### user crontabs

Also check the following directory to see if there are any user's that have created their own crontabs:

For example:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/
total 0
-rw------- 1 saml root 0 Jun  6 06:43 saml
```

Comment: Updated again :)

Comment: @CanadianLuke - does the `syslog` show anything else? `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: I see that the restart happened of the CRON service, but nothing after that (`Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)`

Comment: @CanadianLuke - do you have anacron along with cron setup to run?

Comment: No anacron found

Comment: @CanadianLuke - do the emails show that it's running now or are these emails queued up and just getting delivered now?

Comment: Combined with the comments above, and waiting a full day for the settings to fully apply without rebooting, this did solve it

Comment: when I access those folders I see: "apport  apt-compat  bsdmainutils  cracklib-runtime  dpkg  google-chrome  logrotate  man-db  mdadm  mlocate  passwd  popularity-contest  sysstat  update-notifier-common  upstart"
How do I find and delete the jobs if present?

Comment: @juanIsaza - Each item in that directory will be a user's crons. Look in the files to see what's in them. To remove any of these crons you have to become a respective user (`su - <user>`) and then do a `crontab -l` or `crontab -e` as them to see these. LMK if this makes sense.