# Removed jobs from user Crontab but still its running

Tags: cron

have removed jobs from crontab but somehow it's still running at the scheduled time. I am really not sure what to do.

Below I have also removed user crontab with:

```
sudo crontab -r -u USERNAME
```

```
$sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/
total 4
-rw-------. 1 root root 121 Jan  7 02:28 root
```

This is user's crontab which is empty:

```
$crontab -l
$
```

This is cron log from /var/log (It's not even showing here)

```
Mar 18 21:01:01 u0101 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[65988]: starting 0anacron
Mar 18 21:01:01 u0101 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[65997]: finished 0anacron
Mar 18 21:10:01 u0101 CROND[66668]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Mar 18 21:20:01 u0101 CROND[67392]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Mar 18 21:30:02 u0101 CROND[68097]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Mar 18 21:30:02 u0101 CROND[68098]: (root) CMD (/root/linux-mem.sh 1>/dev/null 2>&1)
Mar 18 21:40:01 u0101 CROND[68851]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Mar 18 21:50:01 u0101 CROND[69614]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
```

What else to lookout for? should I change my script names? I really cant figure out how to stop the jobs from running?

Comment: Why don't you show us that job?

Comment: 05 00 * * 1-7 /home/kile/insertPRD.sh >> /home/kile/Cronlog/Insert.log 2>&1  
This was one of the jobs in user crontab, it's been removed & crontab is completely empty...even cronlog is not showing the above script was triggered however, the script is still running.

Comment: As a matter of now that i give : $ crontab -l
no crontab for USER
$
And yet still job is running at scheduled time. Its weird. There are no other users scheduling this cron job except me

Comment: Add `ps -ef` to the insertPRD.sh script to see what might have launched it.

Comment: `ps -ef| grep 'insertPRD' | grep -v color`   (nothing came up)

still no luck ! I renamed the scripts lets see

Comment: No. Add `ps` to that script, so that you can see which processes run when the script is launched.

Comment: How do you know the script is running?

Comment: The script triggers a mail.

Comment: @berndbausch sorry i'm not following.

Comment: Finally FIGURED OUT!!!!!! Our internal team had cloned our server to UAT environment which created a copy of all jobs/crontab etc. Thanks for all the help1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cron job still running when deleted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85089/cron-job-still-running-when-deleted)

Comment: It was helpful i validated everything as said, but in the end it was a cloned server which was triggering my job. I removed the files from there and it stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally FIGURED OUT!!!!!! Our internal team had cloned our server to UAT environment which created a copy of all jobs/crontab etc. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Amin, thank you!!! You helped me realize the same thing was happening to me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure cron isn't running it - have a [look if there's a process hanging around](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3340/how-can-i-see-what-processes-are-running), or perhaps some other user has it in cron (needs to be done as root).

Comment: What artefact convinces you it's running?